# How to check length of an argument in bash script

Tags: bash, arguments

how can I check the length of an argument in bash script?
Let's say that the length of an argument should not exceed 1.

```
args=("$@")
if [ ${args[0] -gt 1]; then
    echo "Length of arg. 1 must be 1"
fi
```

This however doesn't work properly, since it will check if args[0] > 1 and not len(args[0] > 1):

./sth.sh 2 1 1
"Length of arg. 1 must be 1"

LENGTH is 1, but it still echoes.

I also tried this:

```
args=("$@")
if [ ${#args[0] -gt 1]; then
    echo "Length of arg. 1 must be 1"
fi
```

However, it doesn't echo anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
fi

Or

if test "$#" -ne 1; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
fi
```

Later check the length of each argument like this:

```
for var in "$@"
do
   check=${#var}    
    if [ $check -ne 1 ]; then echo "error" ; exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: Problem is, that I must chech if there is legal number of parameters (in my case 3 and 5 is okay) + if any of those 3 or 5 arguments exceeds the length of 1. I have already did as you said, but now I must also check the length of each argument.

Comment: True, for loop may work, but how do i echo then?
Lets say:

for var in args;
do
if [ ${#var} -gt 1 ]
echo ???

Comment: I've edited the answer to check the length for the arguments.

Comment: I checked your edit and it partly works. However my echo must look like this: "Length of {number of arg whose length is > 1} must be 1."
+exit {number of arg whose lenghth is > 1}

Comment: Declare a variable outside and initialize it to 1 and increment it in the loop, you can use that variable as a marker to indicate the position of the argument.